# Combined JavaScript and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The script below works fine, it combine JavaScript and PHP.
By pressing the button I get its value (`buttonValue`  = 20) and the existing item list (A,B,C) is being replaced by the new list that stopped when `$i <= 10` (1,2,3… 10):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

    var buttonValue = $(':button').val();
    alert(buttonValue);

    $("#City > option").remove(); // remove all items from list
    <?php $i = 1; while ($i <= 10): ?>
    $('<option><?php echo $i; ?></option>').appendTo('#Country select'); 
    <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>
  });
});
</script>

<body>
    <button value="20">click to start</button>
    <div id="Country">
      <select id="City">
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">B</option>
        <option value="">C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to change the PHP loop so that instead `$i <= 10`, it will show `$i <= $the_buttonValue` (assign the button value to show numbers 1,2,3… 20).

I've tried jQuery AJAX functions: `load()`, `get()` or the `ajax()` method, to send the variable to the server but that doesn't seems to solve the above request.

I know that the two sides of PHP and JavaScript are communicate differently and that maybe an AJAX request can get the new requirement to work, but I’m not sure how.

Any tip to make it works as requested, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use JavaScript for that loop?

Comment: Where? How? Can you be more specific in your question?

Comment: How do you set the value of the button (i.e., `value="20"`)?

Comment: @ pete, This is exactly my question, how to assign the var ‘buttonValue’.

Comment: Let me rephrase. Where is the `20` coming from? A client-side input? Is it set by `value="<?php echo $value; ?>"`? Is it just static text in your HTML?

Comment: @ pete, the number 20 is value of the button that the user press. there can be many different buttons.

Comment: Show us your ajax/php attempts.  If PHP has everything you need couldn't you just dump it out to a hidden div for JS to handle?  Your question is very confusing because you are not providing the original PHP code.  Both JS and PHP do loops just fine so show us what it is that you need PHP for.

Comment: @ danronmoon
   <?php View::newInstance()->_exportVariableToView(10); ?>
      <?php while(has_list_cities()) { ?>

I would like to assign ‘buttonValue’  instead the number 10

Comment: My point is that the number `20` does not just magically appear. Something has to put it there, be it other client-side code that you are not showing, other PHP code that you are not showing, or whether it's literally typed as "20" in the HTML source. **How** the number 20 is stored in the value is relatively important to figuring out the easiest way of getting it into PHP for your loop.

Comment: @ danronmoon, I’ve messed up with my ajax attempts, and I didn’t want to confuse the users with complicated wrong solutions. Can you provide your suggestion on how to replace the $i <= 10, with $i <= $the_buttonValue

Comment: Please edit the post with your PHP.  We like seeing attempts, so please post those too.  Believe it or not it makes it easier.

Comment: @ danronmoon, please read my post again: “maybe an AJAX request can get the new requirement to work, but I’m not sure how.” Can you please suggest your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need php for this particular problem but if you must use it for some reason then you can use jquery load() function like:

**your.html**

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

    var buttonValue = $(':button').val();
    alert(buttonValue);

    $("#City > option").remove(); // remove all items from list
    $('#Country').load('your.php?value='+buttonValue+' #Country')
  });
});
</script>

<body>
    <button value="20">click to start</button>
    <div id="Country">
      <select id="City">
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">B</option>
        <option value="">C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

**your.php**

```
<div id="Country">
      <select id="City">

<?php 
    $val = $_GET['value']; //this will be your button value
    $i = 1;
    while (true)
    {
?>
        <option value="">
                    <?php echo $i++; if($i==$val) break; ?>
        </option>
<?php
    }
?>
      </select>
</div>
```

*My first ever stackoverflow answer, hope you will vote up :)*

Comment: @ Arpit Singh, thanks but I can’t see in ‘your.html’ any code calling to ‘your.php’

Comment: @user203952 : $('#Country').load('your.php #Country'), the jquery load() function has its first parameter as the url to which the call will be made , i will edit it now, u should see how i added value=20 inside the url so as to assist GET inside php

Comment: @user203952: Correction $('#Country').load('your.php?value='+buttonValue+' #Country')

Comment: @user203952 i'm sorry i missed out on passing the buttonValue to the php script but i have edited my answer, also keep both the files in same dir

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest method would just to be when the button is submitted push that information to both your Javascript variable and a PHP variable; then base your loop of that equivalent PHP variable because trying to set PHP variables and functions based on a javascript value can be much more difficult making posting AJAX data and getting JSON responces.

You could also just do that loop in javascript but that is all about your preferences. It is just difficult to push javascript variables into PHP variables because PHP is always handled server-side while the javascript is executed client-side.

An example of doing everything in javascript would be; instead of

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){

    var buttonValue = $(':button').val();
    alert(buttonValue);

    $("#City > option").remove(); // remove all items from list
    var i = 1;
    while(i <= buttonValue){
    $('<option>' + i + '</option>').appendTo('#Country select'); 
    i++;
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @ Devon Bernard, I cannot understand your suggestion, please can you show a short code of what you mean.

Comment: @ Devon Bernard, in the original code, the loop is a PHP function (<?php while(has_list_cities()) { ?>, I must use a PHP loop.

Comment: @user203952: I am not exactly sure by what you mean by that because I do not see the context code... but you should just be able to throw this java function within your PHP while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PHP at all:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    var buttonValue = $(':button').val();
    alert(buttonValue);

    $("#City > option").remove(); // remove all items from list
    for (var i = 0; i < buttonValue; i++) {
        $('<option>' + i + '</option>').appendTo('#Country select'); 
    }
  });
});
</script>

<body>
    <button value="20">click to start</button>
    <div id="Country">
      <select id="City">
        <option value="">A</option>
        <option value="">B</option>
        <option value="">C</option>
      </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: @ 0xJoKe, In the original code $i is replaced by a PHP function (<?php echo list_city_name(); ?>), so I must use PHP ($i).